# How can store exact decimal value in database

Tags: php, mysql, types, decimal, sqldatatypes

`1 * 20/100 = 0.2`

I want to store the same value in database how can i do that
I have give column type as `Decimal` and the lenght automatically taking as `(10,0)`

> My issue is it is storing as 0 instead of 0.2

Comment: double or float are your friends in mysql ....

Comment: you can change your table field to `float` from `int`

Comment: You have to change you table filed type to float or varchar

Comment: it worked with float

Comment: I doubt that using float is a good idea - you should definitely read up on data types before you decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No datatype will store `1/3` exactly.

Your example of `20/100` implies the need for `DECIMAL(..., 2)`, where the `...` is a suitable maxinum number of digits *including* the `2`.

Without further insight into where the numbers are coming from or how they will be used, we cannot discuss this further.

Answer (score 1):

Change the limit of that field as (10,2) and then try again. It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use type "double" (10,2) in your database.

double is type and length is 10,2 
it will store like  0.20

if your want to store only single decimal digit the use 10,1

Thanks.

Comment: `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are inexact and involve an extra rounding.  Do not use `(m,n)` with them.